# Got App not found issue when run jar file of actframework

Tags: actframework

i have issue when i run fat jar of actframework which is created using shade plugin.

java -jar jarFile

[image]

I still got App not found issue. What is missing ? Appreciate for you help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@user3242789 please fire a bug report on https://github.com/actframework/actframework/issues

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is because your app dir is not set correctly. Checkout http://actframework.org/doc/faq